# Playing video using UIWebview

Tags: iphone

detailVideo.h

`@interface detailVideo : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
    NSString *urlAddress;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *urlAddress;`

@end

detailVideo.m
`- (void)viewDidLoad {`

```
NSString *reqUrl = urlAddress;

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:reqUrl];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webview loadRequest:requestObj];

//  webView.opaque = NO;

webview.delegate = self;
```

}
The video is working fine.But if i click the Done button,it redircts some other page which consists Replay button.I want switch back from this view?

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can play video in embedded UIWebView, please try this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-mp4\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 412.0)];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:webView];

}
```